# Tips on how to optimize the inner function with a large for loop

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, signal-processing

```
def testing(min_quadReq, stepsize, max_quadReq, S):
    y = np.arange(min_quadReq, max_quadReq, stepsize)
    print("Y", y)
    I_avg = np.zeros(len(y))
    Q_avg = np.zeros(len(y))
    x = np.arange(0, (len(S)))
    debugger = 0
    for i in range(0, len(y)):
        I = np.array(S * (np.cos(2 * np.pi * y[i] * x)))
        Q = np.array(S * (np.sin(2 * np.pi * y[i] * x)))
        I_avg[i] = np.sum(I, 0)
        Q_avg[i] = np.sum(Q, 0)
        debugger += 1
    D = [I_avg**2 + Q_avg**2]
    maxIndex = np.argmax(D)
    #maxValue = D.max()
    # in python is arctan2(b,a) compared to matlab's atan2(a,b)
    phaseOut = np.arctan2(Q_avg[maxIndex], I_avg[maxIndex])
    # returns the out value and the phase
    out = min_quadReq + ((maxIndex + 1) - 1) * stepsize
    return out, phaseOut
```

I'm working on a project where uses DSP to process a signal at get out the relevant data. The code above is from the inner function of a quadrature modulation. From what I have seen this is the part of the code that have the biggest potential to be optimized. For example the two sum function is called about 92k times each and the quadrature function itself 2696 times. I'm not that familiar with python so if any have any suggestion to how a more efficient way of writing it or some good documentation it would be lovely.

The signal S is the input source and it's a array of [481][251]. The outer shell of the quadrature is called on by `quadReq(cavSig[j, :])` just some extra information to show how it's called and how many times.

```
def randomnumber():
    s = np.random.random_sample((1, 251))
    print(s)
    return s
```

randomnumber()

Edit: Added some more information

Comment: Please indent your code properly.

Comment: It can definitely be optimized.  You need to read up on [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html), and [this](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2015/broadcasting-arrays-in-numpy/), and [here](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/intro/numpy/operations.html#broadcasting).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on the Code Review site.

Comment: Please remove this to CodeReview.StackExchange.com.  Also include a full [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) -- add a driver to this that will let others run your code from scratch.

Comment: What can you tell us about _y_, especially the stepsize? It wouldn't divide the length of _S_ by any chance? And the length? Is it much smaller than that of _S_?

Comment: The stepsize is related to the proceeded signal,shown in the added coded. 

Thanks for the reading material, I'll look into it. 

If this is the wrong forum then I will take it into consideration.

Comment: It may be getting better but there's still more numpy expertise here than on CR.  Improvements like this are routine on SO.

Comment: Also the MCVE that Prune cited is a SO requirement.  CR has its own 'rules'

Comment: I think I have fulfilled the req. now.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop produces one `I_avg` value for each element of `y`.  For compactness I could write it as a list comprehension.

```
In [61]: x=np.arange(4)
In [62]: y=np.arange(0,1,.2)
In [63]: [np.cos(2*np.pi*y[i]*x).sum() for i in range(y.shape[0])]
Out[63]: 
[4.0,
 -0.30901699437494745,
 0.80901699437494767,
 0.80901699437494834,
 -0.30901699437494756]
```

But that `y[i]*x` part is just an outer product of `y` and `x`, which can be written with `np.outter`, or just as easily with broadcasting, `y[:,None]*x`.

```
In [64]: np.cos(2*np.pi*y[:,None]*x).sum(axis=1)
Out[64]: array([ 4.        , -0.30901699,  0.80901699,  0.80901699, -0.30901699])
```

Get on to an interactive Python session, and play around with expressions like this.  The best way to learn is by doing and seeing immediate results.  Keep the test expressions and arrays small so you can see immediately what is happening.

Comment: Thanks I will look into it